# Remove prose from a child Tailwind Typography

Tags: css, reactjs, tailwind-css, typography, prose

I want to remove `prose` from the `<code>` section which is dynamically generated so I don't have access to it.

So I need to find a way to remove `prose` from the parent in the classname.

I try different ways :

- not-prose
- prose-code:
- [Customizing default css](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/typography-plugin#customizing-the-css)

But that still doesn't work

```
<Layout isChallenge={true} routerQueryId={routerQueryId as string}>
      <ProseContainer style="">
        {source ? <MDXRemote {...source} /> : <p>Fetching content from GitHub...</p>}
      </ProseContainer>
</Layout>
```

Here I want to edit `<ProseContainer>`style

I try this in `tailwind.config.js`file :

```
typography: {
  default: {
    css: {
      pre: false,
      code: false,
      'pre code': false,
      'code::before': false,
      'code::after': false
    }
  }
}
```

Does anyone know how to remove prose from any section dynamically generated?

EDIT :

This seem to remove everything instead of removing only the code section

```
 theme: {
    typography: {
      DEFAULT: {
        css: {
          pre: false,
          code: false,
          'pre code': false,
          'code::before': false,
          'code::after': false
        }
      }
    },
    extend: {
      fontFamily: {
        sans: ['Inter var', ...defaultTheme.fontFamily.sans]
      }
    }
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try side by side this?

```
<Layout>
  <div>
        {source ? <MDXRemote {...source} /> : <p>Fetching content from GitHub...</p>}
  </div>
  <ProseContainer style="">
        {source ? <MDXRemote {...source} /> : <p>Fetching content from GitHub...</p>}
      </ProseContainer>
</Layout>
```

Comment: That's remove everything and this is not the result I expect

Answer (score 0):

You're overwriting the typography settings instead of extending them. Do this instead:

```
theme: {
  extend: {
    fontFamily: {
      sans: ['Inter var', ...defaultTheme.fontFamily.sans]
    },
    typography: {
      DEFAULT: {
        css: {
          pre: false,
          code: false,
          'pre code': false,
          'code::before': false,
          'code::after': false
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```